Three dots not covering full background
I am trying to cover dots will cover when the page will change but in my current code it is working like indivisual dot I am sharing code and screenshots of current and require UI. enter image description here
{rulebooks.map((_, index) => (
              <View key={index} style={{
                width: 10,
                height: 10,
                borderRadius: 5,
                backgroundColor: index <= this.state.currentIndex ? 'black' : 'transparent',
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: 'gray',
                marginHorizontal: 5
              }} />
            ))}
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity testID="handleNext" style={styles.roundBtn} onPress={this.handleNext} disabled={currentIndex === rulebooks.length - 1}>
            <Text style={{color:'white',fontWeight:'700',fontSize:responsiveFontSize(2.5)}}>{currentIndex === 0 ? 'Get Started' : 'Next'}</Text>
            <Image source={left} resizeMode="contain" style={styles.left} />
          </TouchableOpacity>


You've posted the same image twice ... what's the actual issue?
